# Cyotoscape.js cola extension similar to cola example

Tags: cytoscape.js, webcola

I am using cytoscape.js and the cola extension and I am interested in creating a layout similar to.
[this example](http://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/examples/browsemovies.html)

I would like the neighbours open smoothly like in the example.

Please have look my codepen when i expand the node `layout.run()` is not
working and if i re-create the layout the affects is not the same like in original cola example.

https://codepen.io/kemalhur/pen/rrOzEq

Thanks

Comment: hi Tamer, did you find any work around?

Comment: Hi Aladdin, unfortunately i couldn't. It seems from its source code that cola example has some special logic and not sure it can be easily integrated to the cytoscape.

Comment: Interesting in this as well.